# How to use @support and @media together in Sass?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

Both statements seem to be valid in Sass:

```
@supports (display: -ms-grid) {
  @media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint-sm) {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

**or**

```
@media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint-sm) {
  @supports (display: -ms-grid) {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Are there any solution to use both together? Something like `@media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint-sm) and @supports (display: -ms-grid) {...}`?

Answer (score 3):

Both of those options seem to be valid **SCSS**.

[DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9c60a5112b9599503010b4c5a91c68a2).

But if you want **SASS**, you need to get rid of the delimiters.

[DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/95512441eee2389d7077140b87b3d178)

```
$breakpoint-sm: 420px

@supports (display: -ms-grid)
  @media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint-sm)
    display: block

@media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint-sm)
  @supports (display: -ms-grid)
    display: block
```